# Difference between projects and subgroups in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-8

I want to understand the difference between projects and subgroups in GitLab.

Please help me on understanding the above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Project

A project manages one git repository and adds an issue tracker, a wiki, etc:

See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/index.html#doc-nav

## Groups

Groups can be used to combine several projects under one topic. Examples:

- You could put all your JavaScript projects in a group called "js"
- You could create one group for each of your developer teams; then if somebody new joins a team, you can just add them to the group instead of having to grant developer access for every project.
- Groups can be referred in issues or commit discussions.

See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/index.html#doc-nav

Different groups may have different permissions

## Subgroups

Subgroups are only available in GitLab 9 and above; they allow you to create additional groups inside of groups, e.g. "js/frontend"; this is useful if you are working on a large project with several sub-projects. See the official documentation for some examples:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/subgroups/index.html